# drawing multiple vector3 on a 3d coordinate axis (c#)

Tags: c#, math, vector, 3d, drawing

I need to create a program which draws multiple vector3 in 3 dimensional space, like so: http://www.intmath.com/vectors/7-vectors-in-3d-space.php
the only trouble being I have no idea how to get started with drawing an x,y and z axis and then drawing the vectors. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of program you are going for, but this kind of thing is usually easier in any kind of 3d game engine like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/), for example.